# Why cant I build apps on my PC but I can on my mac? Xamarin

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

So I got my MacBook pro yesterday in hopes of developing some local apps to build on my phone.
And after setting everything up, Visual studio on my mac and XCode, and I already had Visual Studio on my PC things started messing up.
I tried debugging my app on my phone from my PC, with the phone connected to my PC ofcourse, didnt work, so I read around on the internet for a good 4 hours and it said that I should create a blank project in XCode, and for the Signing in preferences I had to choose Team, so I did and it debugged the application on my iphone when my iphone was connected to my Mac,
However I DONT want to code on Mac computers, I want to use my PC.
But everytime I try to debug the application from my PC it keeps saying

> Could not find any available provisioning profiles for iOS.

I am running a iPhone 7 with the version 10.1.1 because I dont want to update due to various reasons.
I tried changing the Deployment target to something really low but that didnt fix it.
Why is this happening?

[Visual representation of what the error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvU7a.png)

[Not sure if this picture helps, this is the project properties > iOS Bundle Signing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csHlf.png)

And my device log is empty aswell.. Why?

[ANother error message saying it doesnt support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ODzt.png)

EDIT

I plugged it into the mac and now its visible in the Device log and I can see stuff happening in the device log but I still cant boot the project on my iPhone

Comment: Are you an enrolled Apple Developer?

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't allow developing for iphone on a non IOS device. This simply means that you can't build apps on a Linux or Windows computer/laptop the normal way. You are stuck on building your project on an IOS device.

There are 2 options to fully develop on a Windows laptop though.

One way of doing so is by using your mac as a gateway to send your app from Windows to IOS to your phone. More info about this can be found here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/

The second option is a newer one called Xamarin Live Player. You don't need to use a mac at all for developing, but you still need a mac if you want to publish the app. This option also works differently from normal development as you need to download an extra program on your phone.
https://www.xamarin.com/live

Comment: Using my mac as a gateway doesnt work, i kep getting the error messages as you can see on the images

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do manual provisioning. Create a development provisioning profile at the Apple Developer site, and have XCode download it for you. Then it should show on your PC for you to select.

See the Xamarin documentation on manual provisioning for some more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=vsmac#creating-a-development-provisioning-profile